# From command line to GUI

Tags: java, user-interface

What is the right approach to end up with a GUI Java program?

Explain: I want to make a program that has a GUI. Should I complete my program as command line application and then creating the GUI? Or start with e.x. WindowBuilder, Java Fx and make it as a GUI application from the beginning?

Assume that I have a user input using Scanner. When I want to end up with GUI should I have to change all the code to take input from JTextField?

Be more specific: I have the following code

```
//Add task to the List
public void AddToList() {
    myList.add(task.setTaskDesc());
    System.out.println("New item " + task.tascDesc + " is added in your task list!");
}
```

The AddToList method takes user (scanner input) and creates a task added in the list. So I have to change ALL the code to become GUI?
Its a general purpose question just to understand which is the normal way to make a full program as most of the programs need a GUI.

Comment: In most tutorials i see how to create a GUI starts as a new application! i didnt find any tutorial to change the application from CLI to GUI. This is the reason of my question

Answer (score 1):

It is best to seperate your algorithm/logic from the user interface (UI). So all input should be passed as function parameter to your logic. Later to you can then decide wether it comes from a graphical user interface (GUI) or is passed over from the commandline. Also the output should be a UI independend datastructure. Then you can visualize it later both as plan Text or graphically.

Comment: I understand what you say, but my question is that later i acctually have to change ALL my code to take user input from GUI, display the output in GUI, even some if/else blocks to become choiseButton. So its like writing all the application from the begining. Am i wrong? I have a small program of 3 classes and i think its already very complicated to make a GUI for it. I cant imagine if its full workink with lets say 50 classes to have change all your code to become GUI programm.

Comment: The idea of abstracting UI from the logic is that you NEVER need to CHANGE your logic. You only write logic once and later ADD a GUI or Command Line Inteface (CLI) around it. Also a boolean choise may be passed as boolean argument

Answer (score 0):

Well, i can tell you from my experience what i consider as a good option.
You want to use the terminal or the console with System class which i consider a good option but only when you have a consola or a terminal. Well, you can use the terminal input arguments and pass them to the main function to other function wich is used in the controller class of you JavaFX application. In this case i will recomend you use only the args as a alternative mode in the inputs that your program can manage. In case that you have used nmap application as example, you can see that the  inputs from the terminal can be provided from the terminal to the GUI application.
But i don't recommend you to use one terminal application or one terminal input for passing values to the GUI terminal, i mean you can but i don't recommend you. 
In case that you want, you can pass values from the main function to as args value to the controller class and manage what do you want, or using System.in or what you want to the java controller class you can do it.

But the best option is to use sceneBuilder for bulding  the application and gives the logic to the javaFXController.java class which is in charge to manage the values.
The first step:
     To build the components from sceneBuilder always providing the fx:id and      the handler name for the component.

Second step:
     Manage the values that you want from the GUI 
Third Step:
     Manage the values from the terminal to the application but it is trivial

Good luck!

Comment: Let me be more clear.Assuming i have a project to make a programm. The programm must do 1,2,3,4,5 thinks. Ex, add task, mark task as completed, print list of tasks, etc. I make the programm and next step is to provide a gui for all this. As my programm is already working the way i want, i have to rewrite everything to become a gui application. So it was better to start building it as GUI programm from the beggining?

Comment: Yes, you are tight or you can separate and to do the application wich uses the console as a module or a class which provides you what you want. After you have the class as a module you can use objects of this class in the controller. In conclusion, you don't have to remove your application which use the console, you only have to change small things. I hope i help you.